# View recent files in Management Studio

Tags: windows, ssms

I trying to find a SQL script that a former colleague of mine used to run periodically. His instructions are to log onto his machine and go to his recent files and select the file.

He doesnt remember where the file physically exists as every time he runs it he would open the file via this method.

My question is how do I access this list? Problem is we wiped his machine and made a copy of his HD. ive tried navigating to \USERS\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\ but there is nothing obvious I can use here.

Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is tracked in the in the following location (depending on your version of SQL) in the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\FileMRUList

[Edit] On a side note, rather than looking for this recent list I would use a grep tool like textcrawler (free, and awesome) to search for a particular string (presumably you remember some sprocs that are called or tables that are accessed by the script) within all .sql files on the hard disk.

Comment: I used a grep tool which crawled his HD but couldnt find anything, so I figured it would have been on the network and that would take days to crawl. Your answer helped me view his recently viewed files which is what I asked for so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS version 18, the registry path to the recent file list is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell\MRUItems{01235aad-8f1b-429f-9d02-61a0101ea275}\Items

Keep in mind, you must restart SSMS for any changes to take effect.